# CSCore: Detect different sounds

Tags: c#, audio, cscore

I'm trying to detect a few sounds that get played.  There are about four sounds of different pitches.  I'm using cscore something like the following...

```
using (WasapiCapture capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture())
{
    capture.Initialize();

    using (WaveWriter w = new WaveWriter(stream, capture.WaveFormat))
    {
        capture.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
        {                
             w.Write(e.Data, e.Offset, e.ByteCount);
        };
        capture.Start();
```

however I can't figure out how to detect the different sounds.  they are known unique sounds and I just need to distinguish between them.  I was thinking of calculating pitch but not sure that is the best way.

does anyone have any ideas or know how I can calculate the pitch?

Comment: If it's different pitches, I suspect you might need something like an FFT to 'cut' the sound into different frequency bands.

Comment: CSCore has an example of FFT processing in its WinformsVisualization sample